# Multi level Approval workflow with dynamic approver

Tags: sharepoint-designer, approval

I'm trying to create a multi level approval workflow with dynamic approver.

I have followed this blog post on creating a dynamic approver. It's very helpful and works well.

https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/sharepoint-custom-approval-workflow-with-dynamic-approvers-using-sharepoint-designer/

However, I need a multi level approver version of it. Does anyone know how to go about it?

Thanks in advance.